# How to discard perforce integration history for a newly-branched and edited file?

Tags: perforce

Let's say I've branched a file in perforce and edited it. Now I'd like to discard the branch history and treat the file as a fresh add. What command accomplishes this?

This scenario arises often because my IDE insists on treating a copy as a branch/edit. After making extensive changes to the copied file, it causes confusion to treat it as a branch/edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can revert the new file and then add it back, without the copy/move.

```
cp /path/to/new/file /path/to/new/file.bak
g4 revert /path/to/new/file
mv /path/to/new/file.bak /path/to/new/file
g4 add /path/to/new/file
```

But, the history is there for a reason.  If one exists, you might want to keep it - it might be helpful to see the lineage (even if muddled) at some point in the distant future.  Consider changing your settings on your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

**In your IDE**:

- Create a **new file** with the new name
- Open the old file
- Select the contents of the old file
- Copy to the clipboard
- Open the new file
- Delete all the contents from the new file
- Paste in the contents of the old file.

Then the IDE will do a new in perforce instead of a branch, the above is only a few keybaord presses if you use your IDE keybaord shortcuts.